# Prevent WebAPI OData Controllers names clashing?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a WebAPI project hosted in Azure which provides JSON web service for a mobile app. I now want to add an OData service to provide data to business users. It looks difficult to to get two separate WebAPI projects hosted within one Web Role so I am trying to get both services running within one project.

The problem I have is that the same Model classes are used for both so that they both expect the same Controller class name, e.g. ProductsController. If I try to put the controllers into different namespaces I get an error:

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Products'.
This can happen if the route that services this request ('odata/{*odataPath}')
found multiple controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces,
which is not supported. The request for 'Products' has found the following
matching controllers: 
MyProj.Controllers.OData.ProductsController
MyProj.Controllers.ProductsController
```

As I cannot specify namespaces in MapODataRoute I am unable to disambigufy the two controllers. Can anyone suggest a solution?

**Update 1**

Some  details on the configuration. The OData configuration is:

```
        config.EnableQuerySupport();

        ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");

        Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
```

and the WebAPI RouteConfig is:

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to resort to using 'O' as a prefix for all the OData controllers to uniquely name them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, WebAPI does not support areas "out of the box", like MVC. You'll need to replace `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`. The details are in the [link](http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/).

Moreover, you can give a try to AttributeRouting.WebApi nuget package (http://attributerouting.net). This feature is already included in WebAPI roadmap.

Comment: Does attribute routing work for OData? How should I use it for my specific scenario? I tried adding `[RouteArea("v1")]` to my OData ProductsController and changing my URL to include v1 but that gave me a 404. Removing the v1 gave me the same error message as above. I have added a detail on the config to my OP.

Comment: OK. What if you change `modelBuilder.EntitySet<Product>("ODataProducts");` and change your controller to `MyProj.Controllers.OData.ODataProductsController`?

Comment: Yes I tried that, but its cheating! ;) I don't really want my urls to be `/odata/ODataProducts`. But thanks for the link to attributerouting as it looks pretty useful anyway.

Comment: I haven't done it (yet) but replacing the `DefaultHttpControllerSelector` looks like the current best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround but as you have suggested you can change the name of the controller slightly for the odata controller (prefix/suffix etc) and then tell odata how to find that controller by implementing IODataRoutingConvention and passing the implementation to .MapODataServiceRoute:

```
public class DefaultODataRoutingConvention: IODataRoutingConvention  
    {
        //Map /odata/{entitySetName} to {entitySetName}ODataController (prevent issue with controller names colliding with existing api controllers
        public string SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            string controllerName = $"{odataPath.NavigationSource.Name}OData";
            return controllerName;
        }

        //return null for action selection i.e. use default odata selection here
        public string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Pass the above custom convention to MapODataServiceRoute:

```
var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault(); 
conventions.Insert(0, new DefaultODataRoutingConvention());  
config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", GetMyODataModel(),new DefaultODataPathHandler(), conventions);
```